# Sort ArrayList using Comparable

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I'm working on a project where I need to be able to sort an ArrayList of Car objects by price. In my Car class, I have

```
public class Car implements Comparable
```

and in the body of the code is the compareTo method:

```
    public int compareTo(Object o)
    {
        Car rhs = (Car)o;

        if (price > rhs.price)
            return 1;
        else if (price < rhs.price)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
```

I just don't understand how to implement this method to sort by price- what does carList need to be compared to? I know this isn't correct but so far this is the sorting method.

```
public void sortByPrice()
{
    Collections.sort(carList.compareTo(o));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:  one syntatical and one conceptual.

The first issue is that while your `compareTo` is *technically* correct, you want to type-bind it to `Car` instead of `Object`.

```
public class Car implements Comparable<Car>
```

Inside of your `compareTo` method you'd then substitute `Object` for `Car`.  You would also want to check for `null`.

The second is that `sortByPrice` sounds specific, but since `compareTo` is comparing based on price, that's somewhat okay.

All you'd need to do is call `Collections.sort` on the actual collection:

```
Collections.sort(carList);
```

Comment: Thank you! this makes a lot more sense to me now

Answer (score 0):

Normally, one sorts a collection using

```
Collections.sort(collection)
```

while `collection` has to implement `Comparable` and `sort` uses the `compareTo` method to sort `collection`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Car` class must implement `Comparable<Car>`. Then your `compareTo` method will have signature:

```
public int compareTo(Car other) {}
```

As per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), this method should:

> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Then given a `List<Car>`, say `list`, you can call `Collections.sort(list)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost done! Only call to `Collections.sort(carList);` and that will by itself, use the overridden `compareTo`.
Actually, when you're not implementing compareTo, you'll have the very basic implementation, and calling `Collections.sort(..)` will use the basic implementation, which is comparing pointers in that case.